# DynamoDB: How to update an item except for one attribute if the attribute already exists

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

So I'm trying to put an Item into a DDB table (nodejs). If the Item has a 'date_created' attribute, I want to update all fields in that Item except for the 'date_created'.

I've looked at conditional expressions and from what I understand it's pretty binary. If condition == true then proceed, if not, then don't. What I'm looking for is to do the put no matter what but don't update 'date_created' if it exists.

Is this possible? Am I even approaching this with the right mindset?

Answer (score 2):

You don't want a PutItem with a ConditionExpression for this case.

You need to use the [UpdateItem](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateItem.html) API. UpdateItem is an "upsert", so if the primary key does not exist, the API will cause a new item to be inserted. This API accepts an [Update Expression](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.UpdateExpressions.html) which can be used to set, modify, and/or remove one or more fields from the item. Update Expressions have a few special functions available to them, and in order to prevent overwriting existing data, you should use `if_not_exists(path, operand)`. If `path` does not exist, DynamoDB will put the result of `operand` at `path`. If `path` does exist, it will be unchanged.

The update expression for your case would look something like this:

```
SET if_not_exists(date_created, :right_now), other_field_1 = :value_1, other_field_2 = :value_2
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't believe DynamoDB supports this natively.

A better solution might have `date_created` on initial put, and `date_updated` on subsequent updates. The initial put is a consequence of some high-level 'new item' kind of operation (like 'Add Employee'). The subsequent updates don't need to be conditional -- they don't include `date_created`, just `date_updated`. And you hide those two attributes within your model layer (that implements `createRecord()` and `updateRecord()`, for example).

Alternatively, do an initial DDB put, including `date_created`, that is conditional on `date_created` being absent. If this conditional request fails, do an update without `date_created`.

Comment: This is wrong. A PUT will completely overwrite any existing data for that primary key whether or not you specify a new value for the `date_created` attribute. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_PutItem.html

Comment: @MatthewPope not sure what I was thinking, yes have updated to indicate update vs put where relevant, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I agree with @jarmod on the best way to do this; however, if you really want to do an update on all fields except the one field you can do an `update` instead of a `put`. In JavaScript you could even generate the update statement based on the keys in the data, and exclude the `date_created` value if it happens to be in the data.